# Did Queen Victoria become more flexible during later years?

Tags: 19th-century, england, rulers

I came across a English exam practice question that basically says Queen Victoria was initially very stubborn but became more flexible during her later years (on formal matters such as the state, rather than personal matters). I want to know if this is in actual history a true claim or a false one.

And if it is indeed true, I want to know some short evidence of each stage as well (I don't want to know details so one or two sentences is fine), that shows she is stubborn when young and softer after getting older.

Note: I am not a native English speaker and I have no prior knowledge about the Queen, so I would appreciate answers even seemingly trivial to Anglophiles.

Comment: I think she was in mourning for years if not a decade or more when her Husband died. There was a Scotsman who came down and basically saved her.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would describe her as stubborn.  Remember that under the British constitution, she had very little political power.  Wikipedia will outline her malleability under Melborne and her objections to Peel. Personally she didn't deal well with Albert's death, which could be perceived as "stubborn".  In my opinion the exam question is flawed because Victoria is not famous for "stubborn".

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "flexible" for the question to be answerable.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: It means compromising and not stubborn.

Comment: @cr001 Stubborn about what? About her menu and daily ablutions? About matters of state? About the governance of her large family? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: About formal decisions such as matters of state. I will update the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: That is a gross oversimplification - much of our **present** understanding of how a *constitutional monarchy should work is a direct consequence of Queen's Victoria's *abdication* of (many of) her then constitutional duties during her mourning for Alfred. She entered her reign with much more constitutional power than she resumed it with.

Comment: All comments are gross oversimplification, but I think this question does not merit deeper discussion of British constitutionalism.

Comment: did she become more flexible?  yeah, she was the first geriatric gymnast.  This comment is made to highlight that entropy evident in this comment stream.  Either answer the question, or don't, but this run on argument in comments does not seem productive in getting an answer.  An answer can include a frame challenge, to offer an answer that also corrects improper assumptions in a question.

Comment: You need to read a good biography of Victoria, of which there are scores. Just go into Amazon, and for a very small amount you will get one downloaded to your Kindle in an instant.